# How to pass Boolean list to and how to retrieve it from Intent

Tags: android

How does one one pass a Boolean list into and intent and how does one retrieve it on the other side?

```
List<Boolean> booleanList= new ArrayList<>();
 booleanList.add(...);

Intent intent = new Intent();
```

So how do I pass booleanList into intent and how do I retrieve it?

Answer (score 0):

If its just a Boolean arraylist, and want to keep things simple, i would suggest to change your Boolean to Integer and use `0` or `1` as your false/true and pass the list using `intent.putIntegerArrayListExtra`

Comment: Thanks this is a workable solution

Comment: @feldman.magoge if it worked fine for you, can you upvote the answer? :)